# Background overflowing border when using border-radius

Tags: css

I have a problem with background-color of an element overflowing it's border when using border-radius. I have seen this problem many times and it isn't a special case.

Here is the description:

I have a `<input type="submit">` which has the following styles:

```
background-color: #FF0000;
border: 2px solid #222222;
border-radius: 5px;
```

And if you look at the picture blow, the background-color is overflowing a little at all 4 rounded corners:

**Note: To see the problem better I used the browser's zoom feature. So the picture is a little larger than it's original.**

[image: The background problem when rendered]

This problem always happens, usually I don't see it because my colors are in similar ranges but when using completely different colors like picture above, it's obvious ...

I believe it is a rendering problem in the browser (Firefox 30 and IE11) since I can't see the same problem using Google Chrome. How can I fix this in Firefox and maybe IE? (IE isn't important)

Comment: ***IE isn't important*** actually FireFox is the same, isn't important.

Comment: Please stick to the subject, Firefox is far better than Chrome from the point of view of me as a web developer for many reasons. Chrome only is suited for normal users, isn't as good as Firefox for advanced users ...

Comment: see this demo http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/GEnUU/ , you'll understand why FireFox sucks much. Its performance is the worst. The so-called ***far better*** you mentioned may be just the better support for Add-ons and Extensions. Note that most of the users in this world are just normal users.

Comment: I can see it same in both FF and Chrome, not sure what is your reason, except form that fact that Chrome always tried to copy Developer Tools from Firefox and Firefox's extensions (Like Firebug) and usually did it wrong, I have a rule  for choosing softwares: a program that does things without your permission, sucks. Chrome tries to update itself without your permission in anyway possible, installs an add on in Firefox, sets up Scheduled Tasks, and even disabling them all, still updates itself as soon as you start it and there is no normal settings to disable it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix this issue in FireFox, looks like there is a simple trick with `background-clip`:

```
background-clip: padding-box;
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H9DH2/2)

There is still another work-around with using linear-gradient background and I found out that setting `background-repeat` to `no-repeat` works:

```
background:linear-gradient(red,red) no-repeat;
```

### [Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/H9DH2/1/)

Comment: i was about to comment/answer with this demo http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/DdtaE. from my side, i do not experiment OP's issue in FF.

Comment: @GCyrillus weird, because I made a demo and see it does exist in FireFox (version 30).

Comment: I did not activate the screen performance in my FF due to some freezing bugs with some flash adverts and my graphic card, might be the reason

Comment: @King King: Thanks, this answer works as long as you set padding to 0. But using padding in inputs is usually done fore getting better looks, if you look at the my picture it's oblivious that the padding is needed. So is there any other work around?

Comment: @King King: I fixed the problem with your idea and using `background-clip: padding-box;`, please update your answer with this since it was your idea and I will answer it, thanks again.

Comment: @GCyrillus: The reason for your demo which isn't having my problem is you are using `<input>` but I used `<input type="submit">`, if you change it in your demo, you will see the problem too.

Comment: @Night2 oh my god, looks really awful in FF with the submit type, thanks pointing at it